# Remove products from checkout page

Tags: woocommerce, checkout

I was wondering, is it possible to remove product related information from the checkout page (this should only be visible in the shopping cart)

Thanks a lot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbKDQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can hide with css:
Add css code to your child theme's stylesheet
Or via Customiser > Additional CSS

```css
.woocommerce-checkout .woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table thead,
.woocommerce-checkout .woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table tbody { display: none; }
```

Comment: @ViorelIancu glad to hear that!

Comment: @ViorelIancu Could you accept answer if it helped you :)